# Speed Up SphericalPlot3D

Tags: plotting, graphics, manipulate

I was wondering if I could speed up `SphericalPlot3D`? I tried editing `PlotPoints`, and `MaxRecursion`, but when I wrap `SphericalPlot3D` with `Manipulate` it fails. I don't want to set `ContinuousAction` to `False`.

```
Manipulate[ SphericalPlot3D[{r, 0, rmax}, {\[Phi], 0, phi \[Pi]}, 
  {\[Theta], 0, theta \[Pi]}, SphericalRegion -> True, PlotRange -> 4, 
  Mesh -> 2, Ticks -> None], 
  {theta, 0.07, 1}, {phi, 0.07, 2}, {rmax, 0.07, 4}, SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

I wanted to layer a whole bunch of shells together to make a solid. {r, 0,rmax} specifies what range of shells' radii I want to create

Comment: Your code does not make sense. You use `r` inside your `Manipulate` which is not defined. Otherwise, it works quite fast.

Comment: Get a better machine; it is very fast and smooth on my laptop. Also try `PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"` in your plotting function to avoid evaluating twice

Comment: The problem might be that your `r` is inefficient to evaluate.  Perhaps tell us what that is to get more help.

Comment: Mel, welcome to this site. Perhaps a recommendation is in order: when you post a question, remain on line caring it and answering comments for an hour or so, as many potential fellow users are going to read it and try answering in that time span. If you just go away after posting your question, it is like showing an "I don't care much" attitude.

Comment: While I did not downvote this, I am puzzled as to who and why upvoted it... It seems impossible to answer this without fixing the things mentioned already by others!

Comment: @acl It's called the pity upvote phenomenon. It has been observed a lot on [so] (see [this discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/93356)). In essence, someone sees a -1 and upvotes it, not because it deserved the upvote, but because they felt bad for the OP. The conclusion was that it was not a problem on [so], but on smaller sites like ours, it might well be.

Comment: @R.M I see. Yes, I think here it is (not for this question, which I guess is just carelessness and easily  fixed). Maybe there should be a rule that upvoters should also attempt an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For nested spherical shells you will need to supply multiple radius values in a list. I think you want something like this (using `Range` to create the list of radii):

```
Manipulate[
 SphericalPlot3D[
  Evaluate@Range[0, rmax, 0.25], {\[Theta], 0, theta \[Pi]}, {\[Phi], 
   0, phi \[Pi]}, SphericalRegion -> True, PlotRange -> 4, Mesh -> 2, 
  Ticks -> None], {theta, 0.07, 1}, {phi, 0.07, 2}, {rmax, 0.07, 4}]
```

[image]

For a proper solid, `RegionPlot3D` will give good results, but it is rather slow.

```
RegionPlot3D[
 Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2] < 0.5 && 
  ArcCos[z/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2]] < 2.4 && ArcTan[x, y] < 1.8, 
  {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, PlotRange -> 0.55, PlotPoints -> 200, 
 Mesh -> False]
```

[image]